# Trying to create a loop/or something to add values under if above has already a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using a code which is working fine as i want. But i am unable to add one thing that is for this function

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G11:I11").copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H2:J2")
```

That whenever i run the code then it will copy the range from `sheet3` and will paste it in `sheet4`range if `Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H2:J2")` has already a value then it will paste the further copied value under this range `Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H2:J2")`

and that range will be `Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H3:J3")`
if i again run the code it will paste values `("H4:J4")` because row 2 and three has already values.

same for

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").copy
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")
```

like this
[image]

Sheet link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/105C29uWLfL6XpOZPceNEAEpQATuNjgXI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you need all the time copying these ranges: "B7" followed by "B11:G11", or need to also iterate on the in the Sheet1/Sheet3?

Comment: I will the run code when different values will be updated in the range which will be copied for pasting. So data will be different. I pasted this just as an example.

Comment: So, no need of iteration in the sheet where copying from. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Then, please test the code I posted and send some feedback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub restCopyOnLastEptyRow()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet, lastR As Long
 
 Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set sh3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")
 Set sh4 = Worksheets("Sheet4")
 lastR = sh4.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
 sh4.Range("A" & lastR).Value = sh1.Range("B7").Value
 
 lastR = sh4.Range("H" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
 sh4.Range("H" & lastR).Resize(1, 3).Value = sh1.Range("G11:I11").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. but its not working for Sheet4  i have updated the sheet link please have a look. https://ibb.co/sqb99Tg

Comment: You copied it too fast...:) I corrected the last code line. It is not `Resize(0, 3).Value`, as initially. It is `Resize(1, 3).Value`... I did not test the code. Please, use the actual version. In fact, the last code line should be replaced...

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Because i was not aware that how to ask this thing. But you brilliantly guess what i want. Thank you so much @FaneDuru